# Gallery and fading edges

Tags: android, android-layout, gallery

I have a gallery where I have a bitmaps. This is code:

```
    // Bitmap snoop = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), mImageIds[position]);
   // i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
   // i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // will results in a much smaller image than the original
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/DinEgen/"+name.get(position), options);
        Bitmap img = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( b, width, height, true );
         b.recycle();
    i.setImageBitmap(img);
    //i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
    i.setGallery(g);
    i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(width, height));

    return i;
```

When I start application everything looks ok. Like on the picture:
[image]

and when I go to next page everything looks bad:
[image]

Color is lighter and on left side is something like edge with good color. When I back color is lighter too and this edge is on right side. I used in gallery

android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="0px"

but still doesn't work. Any idea why color is changing and why when I go to next page I see this edge? Any ideas why this is happens?

Edit1: I resolve one problem with margins. I add 30 to width in:  `i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(width+30, height))` but still colors are lighter after go to next page. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following to stop image overlapping and thus eliminating your problem :

```
Gallery gallery= (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.gallery);
gallery.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
```